# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When i click on send button i got this error message:
"The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

My view:

```
<form action="" method="post">

@csrf
<h1> Gmail Sender </h1>

        <div class='form-group'>
            <label>Email:</label>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <input name="email" type="email" placeholder= "Email to .."/>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class='form-group'>
            <label>Subject:</label>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <input name="subject" type="subject" placeholder= "Email to .."/>
          </div>
        </div>

          <div class='form-group'>
            <label>Content:</label>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <textarea  class="form-control" name="txtDescription"
             id="txtDescription" cols="30" rows="3" ></textarea>
          </div>
          </div>

          <button> SEND</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
 @endsection
```

My controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Mail\MyMail;

class MyMailController extends Controller
{
public function sendMail(Request $request){
$this->validate($request,[
'email'=>'required',
'subject'=>'required',
'content'=>'required',
]);

   $myMail= new MyMail(
      $request->input('subject'),
    $request->input('content')
    );

   Mail::to($request->input('email'))->send($myMail);
   return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Email sent successfully. to:' .$request->input('email'));
}
}
```

my route:

```
Route::view('/sendmail', 'sendmail');
Route::post('/' , 'MyMailController@sendMail');
```

I want to send email. But when I click on send button, I got this error message "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

Comment: Your form action is empty, try to add your route in.
Because, when submit a form with empty action, it's submit it self.

Comment: `form action=""` blank???

Answer (score 0):

I use a named route for a better management in form action.

```
Route::post('/' , 'MyMailController@sendMail')->name('sendMail');
```

In your view dont forget to add action to your form

```
<form action="{{ route('sendMail') }}" method="post">
```